# creating new svn project with eclipse

Tags: svn, eclipse-plugin

I am taking an existing project in svn. importing it into eclipse. then disconnecting this project from the svn server. and then trying to place this project back in svn under a different folder. esentially i am trying to create a second copy of this project.

it appears to run as expected but after I select to share the project all of the items in the project show a question mark (in eclipse) but only the top level project folder appears in svn if i browse the directory via a web browser.

what could the issue be? where should i look for any error messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not make the copy within Subversion and then check out the copy?

```
svn cp svn+ssh://path/to/project svn+ssh://path/to/copy/of/project
svn co svn+ssh://path/to/copy/of/project
```

Comment: ahh ok... i could just right click and copy and paste in the SVN repository perspective in eclipse. Man i was making that hard thanks.